# opencv4nodejs installation issue

Tags: node.js, opencv, npm

I am Facing trouble in installing opencv4nodejs in windows, i am getting following error.

> opencv-build@0.0.15 install C:\Users\Mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\opencv4nodejs\node_modules\opencv-build
>   node ./install.js
>   info install if you want to use an own OpenCV installation set OPENCV4NODEJS_DISABLE_AUTOBUILD
>   info install library dir does not exist: C:\Users\Mypc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\opencv4nodejs\node_modules\opencv-build\opencv\build\lib\Release
>   info install running install script...
>   ERR! Error: Command failed: git --version
>   'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! opencv-build@0.0.15 install: `node ./install.js`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the opencv-build@0.0.15 install script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>   npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git was not installed in windows, that was the issue. it's working perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

Git needs to be installed, it will solve this problem

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).